# Address coming from Geocoder is in English

Tags: android, gps, geocoding

I want to do an application which gets the current address; country name, city name and district name. And then I have 3 spinner which are having all country names, city names and district names in Turkish.

When I get the address using GPS and Geocoder, I want to match them with the names in my spinners.

The problem is the address coming from geocoder is in English. And so, it does not match with my countries in my spinner. So I cannot select true country with programatically.

Here is my related code:

```
//In here I add countries coming from web service into countries array.
for(int i=0;i<responseInfo.size();i++) {
    String name = responseInfo.get(i).getName();
    countries.add(name);
    //If country name is equals to country name coming from gps 
    //then I hold it in selectedCountry variable. 
    //But "Turkey" != "Türkiye" so this if block does not work
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(foundAddress.getCountryName()))
    {
        selectedCountryId = (String)responseInfo.get(i).getId();
        selectedCountry = responseInfo.get(i);

    }
}

//In this method, when I get country name from the item in addresses array
//it returns in English
public List<Address> findAddressFromLatLng(double latitude, double longitude) 
{
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if ((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() != 0)) {
        return addresses;
    }
    return null;
}
```

In another device, I have no problem. Country name coming from geocoder is in Turkish (which means Geocoder have Turkish names also). Probably it is because of device language.

I tried to change this line but I can't find Turkish as locale:

```
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docs for [`Geocoder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) suggest that setting a `Locale` is exactly what you need. There's no predefined `Locale` for Turkish, but you can easily define one:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I need  =)